# I get an error message when installing Casey.just using winget for a hyperledger fabric project

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, winget, just

trying to install Just [Casey.Just] using this code in powershell for a Hyperledge fabric project

```
winget install --id Casey.Just --exact
```

after a while of showin this: `Downloading https://github.com/casey/just/releases/download/1.17.0/just-1.17.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.zip`

I get an error message

```
An unexpected error occurred while executing the command:
InternetOpenURL() Failed
0x80072ee2 : unknown error
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Found a solution on this site: https://windowsreport.com/fix-windows-8-1-windows-10-update-error-0x80072ee2/ (Solution nos 4 helped.)

Comment: You would also need to run PowerShell as an administrator..